# Geofire atualizando localização em background

Tags: android, firebase

Estou fazendo um aplicativo , o sistema de localização é parecido com o do uber , que precisa enviar a localização para o firebase de 3 em 3 segundos , pra obter a localização atual ao vivo , porém quando o app está em segundo plano , ele para de atualizar , podem me ajudar?

o código que envia os dados para o firebase é esse

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Common.mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (Common.mLastLocation != null )
    {
        if (location_switch.isChecked())
        {
            final double latitude = Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            //// PASSAR DADOS PARA O FIREBASE
            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                    // ADICIONA MARCADOR NO MAPA
                    if (mCurrent != null)
                        mCurrent.remove();
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))

                            .title("Voce"));



                    /// Movimentar camera para sua posicao
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15.0f));
```

Comment: Quando fecha a Activity,  você mata o mGoogleApiClient?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski quando minimiza ja mata sozinho nao mata?

Comment: http://adavis.info/2014/09/android-location-updates-with-the-fusedlocationapi.html olha esse exemplo! ele pausa, e no onResume volta

Comment: O ideal seria separar em duas partes: Um serviço que pegue a localização e envia par ao servidor. E a tela, apenas consumir os dados deste serviço.